# Can a discrete function have an asymptote?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I have this function which approaches zero in discrete steps:

$$\frac{1}{2^{int(x)}}$$

My question is that although this function shows asymptotic behaviour in that it approaches $$y=0$$ does it still have an asymptote even though it isn't continuous?

Comment: What do you mean by "have an asymptote"?

Comment: What is the definition of asymptote you are using? In the ones I know, continuity is not involved.

Comment: Is that supposed to be ${1\over2^{int(x)}}$? If so, can you edit?

Comment: Is this about Big-Oh notation huh?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Fixed, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

One usually says that a function $f:(a,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ has horizontal asymptote $y=c$ if $$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=c \tag1$$
The function $f(x)=2^{-\lfloor x\rfloor  }$ satisfies (1) with $c=0$ and therefore has horizontal asymptote $y=0$.